# How is the byte[] array with 0 element allocation working with InputStream (readAllBytes)

Tags: java, arrays, byte, inputstream

How can a byte array with 0 memory allocation (byte[] arr = new byte[0]) take bytes read from InputStream?

Below is my code

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        try {
        InputStream resourceAsStream = ArrayBasics.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.json");
        bytes = resourceAsStream.readAllBytes();        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        } catch (Exception noSuchFileException) {
             System.out.println("Some exception");
        }
```

I would expect the code to fail and throw out of bounds error (as it would do if I try bytes[0] = 100;) But the "bytes" actually show the contents in the console without any error or warnings

Comment: `bytes = resourceAsStream.readAllBytes();` is somewhat important. That byte variable is now being assigned an array of bytes with significant length.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `bytes` only references an array initialized to length 0 *at the beginning*.

But in your `try`-block, you reassign a *new* array to `bytes`: The new (and already populated) array *of appropriate length* is now referenced by `bytes`.

With that reassignment, we essentially discard the zero-length array.

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
try {
  // ...
  bytes = resourceAsStream.readAllBytes();
}
```

---

No copying into the array first referenced by `bytes` is happening! In fact, if `bytes` is never read before its assignment in the `try`-block, then that assignment may even be its first:

```java
byte[] bytes; // Declaration of variable `bytes`
try {
  // ...
  bytes = resourceAsStream.readAllBytes(); // First initialization of `bytes`!
}
```